# rails joining two tables together

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to join two tables together. I haven't created the 2nd table as of yet but the first one already exists.

Basically I have this web scrape returning data like:

```
[
  ["formatted_sum_fees", "&Acirc;&pound;5.60"],
  ["formatted_price", "&Acirc;&pound;46.50"],
  ["formatted_sum_fees", "&Acirc;&pound;4.50"],
  ["formatted_price", "&Acirc;&pound;37.50"],
  ["formatted_sum_fees", "&Acirc;&pound;3.30"],
  ["formatted_price", "&Acirc;&pound;27.50"]
]
```

I want to place this in a table. And link all these things that are returned from my webscrape to the event.

The new table will have at a guess this structure:

```
ID|EventID|Price|Fees
```

How would I go about saving this information (from above) into the new table against an event id?

Then I guess if I want to use it in the controller I would be able to call something set in the model? 
The event is being created via a raketask. The webscrape can be put into the same task
I started to do this but got confused quite fast.

Comment: What table do you currently have?  how are you planning on using the data?

Answer (score 0):

you have to add relation between these two tabels i.e in `table_2` model  add `belongs_to table_1` line

& when you create `table_2` add `event_id` equal to `tabel_1` id.

see links below http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to

&

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html